# Change Appendix pagestyle

Tags: header-footer, appendices

After the title page "Appendices" since I have a doublepage, openright document, there is a blank page and then the Appendix A.

```
   \documentclass[a4paper,11pt,titlepage,twoside,openright]{book}
   \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
   \usepackage[italian,english]{babel}
   \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
   \usepackage[titletoc,page]{appendix}
   \usepackage{lipsum}

   \begin{document}

   \chapter{Intro}
   \lipsum
   \lipsum

   \begin{appendices}

   \chapter{First}
   \lipsum

   \chapter{Second}
   \lipsum


   \end{appendices}


   \end{document}
```

I would like to change that stile form blank to plain (just with the page number).
I tried to put

```
    \begin{appendices}
    \thispagestyle{plain}
```

But it is not working.
I saw on the package info were I should change the style, but I don't know how to do it.

```
     \newcommand{\@chap@pppage}{%
     \clear@ppage
     \thispagestyle{plain}%
     \if@twocolumn\onecolumn\@tempswatrue\else\@tempswafalse\fi
     \null\vfil
     \markboth{}{}%
     {\centering
     \interlinepenalty \@M
     \normalfont
     \Huge \bfseries \appendixpagename\par}%
     \if@dotoc@pp
     \addappheadtotoc
     \fi
     \vfil\newpage
     \if@twoside
     \if@openright
     \null
     \thispagestyle{empty}% I should change this empty to plain
     \newpage
     \fi
     \fi
     \if@tempswa
     \twocolumn
     \fi
     }
```

Can anybody tell me how to change that?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: But I would just like to change that part of the package. I guess I can do it with a renewcommand o makeatother-makeatletter. Am I wrong?

Comment: Which package? `appendix`? And which document class? That's why a MWE is needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've found the right piece of code that has to be modified!

You simply have to change `\newcommand` to `\renewcommand` since the command is already defined and put the code between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` because of the presence of the character `@` in the code (see [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8351/27635)), and obviously change

```
\thispagestyle{empty}
```

to

```
\thispagestyle{plain}
```

that means:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@chap@pppage}{%
  \clear@ppage
  \thispagestyle{plain}%
  \if@twocolumn\onecolumn\@tempswatrue\else\@tempswafalse\fi
  \null\vfil
  \markboth{}{}%
  {\centering
   \interlinepenalty \@M
   \normalfont
   \Huge \bfseries \appendixpagename\par}%
  \if@dotoc@pp
    \addappheadtotoc
  \fi
  \vfil\newpage
  \if@twoside
    \if@openright
      \null
      \thispagestyle{plain}%
      \newpage
    \fi
  \fi
  \if@tempswa
    \twocolumn
  \fi
}
\makeatother
```

So, if you change your MWE to:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,titlepage,twoside,openright]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian,english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[titletoc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@chap@pppage}{%
  \clear@ppage
  \thispagestyle{plain}%
  \if@twocolumn\onecolumn\@tempswatrue\else\@tempswafalse\fi
  \null\vfil
  \markboth{}{}%
  {\centering
   \interlinepenalty \@M
   \normalfont
   \Huge \bfseries \appendixpagename\par}%
  \if@dotoc@pp
    \addappheadtotoc
  \fi
  \vfil\newpage
  \if@twoside
    \if@openright
      \null
      \thispagestyle{plain}%
      \newpage
    \fi
  \fi
  \if@tempswa
    \twocolumn
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{Intro}
\lipsum
\lipsum

\begin{appendices}

\chapter{First}
\lipsum

\chapter{Second}
\lipsum


\end{appendices}


\end{document}
```

you will obtain you want.